# Website Search with no database

Tags: ruby, middleman

I am currently about to build a website for a client. For static content I am going to use middleman.
The website consists of a series of categories and inside each there are several products with their own html page.
For example: cars.html has a series of links inside of it that go to corolla.html or accord.html

I was planning on building the site using only middleman, and generating an html page for every product item inside a yaml file. Doing it this way could really speed up development (since products are not added regularly, almost all products are going to be added at once), but this means no database is being used.

The issue I am having is that the site needs to have a search box (not Google Search) so that users can quickly jump to the relevant page, but without a proper database I am not sure if this can be done. 
What tools could I use to archieve this?

I have been looking at alternatives such as Ruby on Rails or Wordpress but I feel it might be overkill.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Nick

Comment: It's not a search box, but you could create a static index page. Based on this idea, you could create a dropdown box with predefined search keys.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [Swiftype](https://swiftype.com/).
Should work with a static site with JavaScript enabled.

No, I'm not affiliated with Swiftype. I just think it is a cool service, though it might cost a few bucks in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'm going to check it out.

Comment: In the end I'll have to use a regular database. Thanks for the tip though, looked promising!

Answer (score 1):

This is potentially useful example of search for middleman:

https://github.com/joelhans/middleman-search-example